# python module giving boost::program_option like functionality

Tags: python, module, boost-program-options

Is there any boost::program_options like module for python

Comment: It would be helpful if you said what the module actually did. Don't assume python programmers are familiar with 3rd party C++ libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For command-line options, you can use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) or (deprecated) [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) or (even older) [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html#module-getopt). For config files, there's [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html).